# Optimal value of amount of water in a water rocket to fly to the highest altitude

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I am currently doing expermients with a water rocket (LPT side-remark: this is highly enjoyable if you're parent of a 6-12 year old kid!)

[image]

There is an initial quantity of water of height $x$ centimeters in the plastic bottle, and the rest is air:

[image]

After pumping, when the pression is high enough, the tip of the pump cable detaches from the bottle, and the rocket takes off and reaches a maximum altitude $f(x)$ in the air.

I am more specialized in math, so my memories about mechanics/physics are a bit far, but here is my question:

**Which equations should I use to find the optimal value of $x \in [0, 30]$ so that the rocket flies to the highest altitude?**

I think we can appromixate the bottle as a cylinder of height 30 cm and diameter 10 cm.

Comment: There are YouTube videos showing this exact thing, and people who have been flying water rockets for years who can give you tips.  Also note - when I taught at the high school level, they had equipment that measured thrust vs. time.  The data clearly indicated that air escapes the bottle with water in a chaotic fashion.  Your assumed equations won't work until you can prevent this (hence the reference to the YouTube videos).

Comment: @DavidWhite Can you describe the chaos a little more? And does it make the zenith a little unpredictable?

Comment: It is much depends on the initial pressure you can inject into the bottle. What is the tpical  value for the pressure can be reached,

Comment: @ytlu About $4\mathrm{bar}$ I believe.

Comment: @Gert What would be the main techniques involved (if, as a first estimation, we let the chaotic behaviour aside)? Would it be fluid mechanics equation? Simple newtonian force estimation? Something else?

Comment: @Basj I think (but kind of guessing here) *the Rocket Equation* (Tsiolkovsky).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this existed! This equation has a cool name by the way! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Comment: @Basj You will also need a relationship between (decreasing) pressure and water ejection velocity. Bernoulli might work there.

Comment: I think I might (note caveat) put an answer together.

Comment: @Gert, on very short time intervals, the pressurized air in the bottle tunnels its way through the water.  When it does, the air velocity goes way up, the thrust drops dramatically, the pressure in the bottle falls rapidly, and when the water covers the nozzle again, the thrust vs. time is somewhat lower than expected.  This action alternates between air and water leaving the rocket, on VERY short time intervals and in an unpredictable pattern.

Comment: @Gert, regarding the predicted zenith, that zenith normally assumes that only water leaves the nozzle until all the water is exhausted.  Since this is not the case, the equations that are used to model the physics of the water rocket are invalid unless you can find a way to keep air from exiting the nozzle prematurely.  That is why I referred the OP to the YouTube videos.

Comment: @DavidWhite That's very clear, thanks.

Comment: @Gert How did you know it would be 4 bar? We made the water rocket fly yesterday, and I confirm it's 4bar, good guess!

Comment: @Basj I must have read that somewhere. And I used that pressure in a PET bottle for some chemical experiment. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @DavidWhite *unless you can find a way to keep air from exiting the nozzle prematurely.* There's a relatively simple way of achieving that: place an almost frictionless piston between air and water. Or a very flexible membrane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily done (as long as you're willing to accept some assumptions) by numerical simulation.  I have done it, and can post the Matlab code if that is helpful. Incidentally, for the parameters I chose (rocket volume 2 L, drag coefficient 0.4, initial pressure 100 psi, etc.) the maximum height of 112 m is reached for a fill volume of 0.63 L.

Some interesting/useful facts:

The thrust is twice the internal pressure times the nozzle area (yes, counterintuitively, twice).

As the air expands, its pressure drops more than it would at constant temperature due to adiabatic cooling.

Once all the water's gone, you get an additional boost as the remaining air is expelled (you can verify this empirically by launching the rocket with no water--if you haven't tried it, you'll be surprised by how high it goes). This bit requires (for me) some fudging, as the air jet, which will remain sub-sonic, loses a lot of its energy to friction.

Edit--here's the code as requested in a comment:

```
function h_max = apex_height(V_w)

% INPUT: V_w, volume of water (L)
% OUTPUT: h_max, maximum height achieved (m)

% ROCKET DESIGN PARAMETERS
m_r = 135;                %mass of empty rocket (g)
V_r = 2;                  %volume of rocket (L)
D = 7/8;                  %diameter of nozzle (in)
D_r = 2.55;               %diameter of rocket (in)
p = 100;                  %initial pressure (psi)

% EMPIRICAL PARAMETERS
C = .4;                   %drag coefficient
e = .3;                   %energy efficiency of air burst

% SIMULATION PARAMETERS
dt = .0001;               %thrust phase time increment (s)
dT = .01;                 %coast phase time increment (s)
N = 5000;                 %max number of time steps

% ENVIRONMENTAL PARAMETERS
atm = 101325;             %atmospheric pressure (Pa)
gamma = 1.4;              %ratio of specific heats for air
rho = 1000;               %density of water (kg/m^3)
rho_a = 1.2;              %density of air (kg/m^3)
g = 9.8;                  %gravity (m/s^2)

% DERIVED QUANTITIES
V_r = V_r/1000;           %volume of rocket (m^3)
V_w = V_w/1000;           %volume of water (m^3)
V_A = V_r - V_w;          %initial air volume (m^3)
V_a = V_A;                %instantaneous air volume (m^3)
D = D*.0254;              %diameter of nozzle (m)
D_r = D_r*.0254;          %diameter of rocket (m)
A = pi*D^2/4;             %area of nozzle (m^2)
A_r = pi*D_r^2/4;         %rocket cross section area (m^2)
P = atm*p/14.7;           %initial relative pressure (Pa)
p = atm + P;              %absolute pressure (Pa)
m_r = m_r/1000;           %mass of empty rocket (kg)
m = m_r + V_w*rho;        %mass of rocket + water (kg)
m_a = V_A*rho_a*p/atm;    %mass of air in rocket (kg)
M = m_a - V_r*rho_a;      %mass of expelled air (kg)
thr = 2*A*P;              %thrust (N)
C = C/2*A_r*rho_a;        %drag coefficient (kg/m)
v_r = 0;                  %rocket velocity (m/s)
v_w = sqrt(2*P/rho);      %exhaust (water) velocity (m/s)
time = 0;                 %time since launch (s)
I = zeros(N,1);           %initialize vectors
p = [p; I];               %rocket pressure vector
v_r = [v_r; I];           %rocket velocity vector
time = [time; I];         %time vector

% THRUST PHASE CALCULATION
i = 1;
while V_w>0         %while there's still water
    i = i+1;
    a = (thr - C*v_r(i-1)^2)/m - g; %acceleration
    time(i) = time(i-1) + dt;       %STEP time
    v_r(i) = v_r(i-1) + dt*a;       % and rocket velocity
    V_a = V_a + dt*A*v_w;           % and air volume
    V_w = V_r - V_a;                %COMPUTE water volume
    p(i) = p(1)*(V_A/V_a)^gamma;    %    and pressure
    thr = 2*A*(p(i)-atm);           %    and thrust
    v_w = sqrt(2*(p(i)-atm)/rho);   %    and water speed
    m = m_r + rho*V_w;              %    and mass
end
p = p(1:i);
h = cumsum(v_r(1:i))*dt;        %compute height
h = [h; zeros(N+1-i,1)];        %initialize height vector

% AIR BURST CALCULATION         (this part is not perfect)
E = (p(i)-atm)*V_r;             %energy stored at burnout
V = sqrt(2*e*E*M/m_r/(M+m_r));  %air burst velocity boost
v_r(i) = v_r(i) + V;

% COAST PHASE CALCULATION
while h(i)>0        %while the rocket is still in the air
    i = i+1;
    s = sign(v_r(i-1));               %up or down
    a = -C*v_r(i-1)^2/m*s - g;        %acceleration
    time(i) = time(i-1) + dT;         %STEP time
    h(i) = h(i-1) + v_r(i-1)*dT;      % and height
    v_r(i) = v_r(i-1) + dT*a;         % and velocity
end
h = h(1:i); time = time(1:i); v_r = v_r(1:i);

% % PLOT THE TRAJECTORY
% plot(time,h*3.281)
% xlabel 'time (s)', ylabel 'height (ft)'

h_max = max(h);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Oh yes, it would be wonderful if you can post the code! (Maybe I can convert to Scilab or Python as well, or run in an online version of Matlab?)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you take into account the gravity that pulls the rocket to the ground, with a varying weight of the bottle? (the more water, the heavier). If I remember correctly, an empty 2L bottle is ~ 35 grams.

Comment: I added the code to the answer.  Octave should be able to run it, and is free, or you can translate it as you say.  Certainly gravity is included--otherwise the rocket would never stop going up.

Comment: Thanks so much @Ben51. I've been able to run it online on cocalc.com but it's not super easy. I wonder if there is an easy way to host your code on Github as a Jupyter Notebook, so that anyone can run it directly in the browser? This would be super great.

Comment: PS: did you find 0.63L by trial and error? i.e. you started with 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ..., 1.0, etc. and then you found 0.63 by binary search? Or did you pack your whole code inside a function of parameter `V_w`, found the maximum of the curve for this specific `V_w`, called `M(V_w)`, and then you did a plot of $V_w \mapsto M(V_w)$, to notice the maximum is attained for $V_w = 0.63$? If you have this code, feel free to include it, if not I'll do it but I am super slow with Octave (10 times slower than with Python), because I don't know nothing about the syntax (0-indexing vs 1-indexing, etc.)

Comment: @Basj I wrote it as a function with water volume as an argument so that it could be called by another script in order to plot max height vs fill. I figured it would be easier to read/understand the code with that part stripped off.

Comment: @Basj I have edited the posted code into a function called $\text{apex_height}$, so you can call it with fill volume as an argument.  I'd rather not include the code here to generate a plot of height vs fill because that doesn't contain any physics.

Comment: Thanks again @Ben51. For future reference and future readers, it would still be interesting to keep your 3 lines of code that generate the plot of the trajectory, it would be great if you reinclude it :)

Answer (score 2):

Accurate math/physics modeling of a water rocket is probably very, very difficult but all models have humble beginnings, can be refined in time, supplemented with empirical data and may yet provide *some* useful insights.

The first port of call would probably be the [Rocket Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation).

Its main insight is that:

$$\Delta v=V_{exh}\ln\Big(\frac{m_0}{m_f}\Big)$$

so that for a constant exhaust velocity $V_{exh}$ and mass ratio $\frac{m_0}{m_f}$, the velocity increase $\Delta v$ is given by the above formula. This suggests that higher fill leads to higher final velocity.

But for a real water bottle, the exhaust speed will not be constant because the air pressure actually rapidly decreases. It can be (crudely) modeled as an adiabatic expansion.

Flow of water (presumed here water only) through the nozzle could be approximated with Bernoulli's Equation (ignoring the gravitational term, as well as water viscosity).

These three elements could (note caveat) be combined into a simple model for $v(t)$, as a function of initial mass of water and initial air pressure.

Because $v(t)=\frac{\rm{d}h(t)}{\rm{d}t}$, then:

$$h(\Delta t)=\int_0^{\Delta t}v(t)\rm{d}t$$

where $\Delta t$ is the total 'firing time'. To that height then has to be added the 'free flight' height to calculate the zenith: $h_z=h(\Delta t)+h_{ff}$

So far we have ignored drag, usually modeled as:

$$F_D=\frac12 \rho C_DAv^2$$

The drag coefficient $C_D$ could be strongly reduced by mounting a shallow cone on the rockets upside.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll study this over the next weeks, I didn't know about the [drag coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient), very interesting, as well as the rocket equation! I'll try with numerical simulation as well.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try a simple model. Assume the cross-section of the bottle $A cm^2$, the mass is the mass of water $m(x) = m_0 + A x$, $m_0$ is the mass of the bottle (in CGS unit, the density of water equals to 1); and the pressure $P(x) = P_0 \frac{L-x_0}{L-x}$, where $L$ is the height of bottom, 30 cm, and $x_0$ the intial water level, the parameter of optimization. $P_0$ denotes the initial pressure of the bottle. Assume that the ejection speed a constant $u_0$. All in CGS unit, $\rho_{water} = 1$.

- the mass $m(x) = m_0 + A x$,
- pressure $P(x) =  P_0 \frac{L-x_0}{L-x}$,
- ejection speed $u_0$, a constant.
- ejection speed and water level: $u_0 B = -A \frac{dx}{dt}$, where $B$ is the area of ejection nozzle (the bottle's opening).

Rocket motion from conservation of momentum (with a constant ejection speed $u_0$):

$$ \tag{1}
 dv = - u_0 \frac{dm}{m(x)} - g dt.
$$

$dv$ is the change of rocket's speed $v(t+dt) - v(t)$. The relation between time $t$ and water level $x$ can be find from volume flux $u_0 B$:

$$ \tag{2}
t = \frac{A}{u_0 B} \left( x_0 - x \right).
$$

integral the above equation Eq.(1):

$$ \tag{3}
    v(x) = u_0 \ln \frac{m_0 + A x_0}{m_0 + A x} - \frac{g A}{u_0 B}\left( x_0 - x \right)
$$

The second term is indeed $ g t $ by replacing $t$ in term of $x$.

At $x = 0$ running out of water, the speed of rocket in this moment is:

$$ \tag{4}
    v(x= 0) = u_0 \ln \frac{m_0 + A x_0}{m_0} - \frac{g A}{u_0 B} x_0.
$$

At this moment $t(0) =\frac{A x_0}{u_0 B} $, the height of rocket  $h(0)$:

$$
 h(x=0) = \int_0^{t(0)} v(t) dt = \int_{x_0}^{0}  v(x) \frac{dt}{dx} dx =  \int_{0}^{x_0} v(x) \frac{A}{B  u_0} dx
$$

This integral can be done by using $\int \ln x dx = x \ln x - x$:

$$ \tag{5}
 h(x=0) = \frac{m_0}{B} \ln\frac{m_0 + A x_0}{m_0} - \frac{A x_0}{B} - \frac{1}{2} g \left(\frac{A x_0}{u_0 B}\right)^2.
$$

The last term is $\frac{1}{2} g t^2$ in free-fall motion.

After the water run out, the rocket is still moving upward. There still a final trip to reach the top position where the speed is zero. In this moment, the rocket has speed $v(x=0)$ from Eq.(4), and may add an addition impulse from the high pressure in the bottle burst ( refer to Ben51, one of other answers to this problem,)  say $v_i$. The total top distance the rocket travel is then:
 
$$\tag{6}
h_{total} = \frac{ \left( v(x=0) + v_i \right)^2}{2g} +  \frac{m_0}{B} \ln\frac{m_0 + A x_0}{m_0} - \frac{A x_0}{B} - \frac{1}{2} g \left(\frac{A x_0}{u_0 B}\right)^2.
$$

where $v(x=0)$ is given in Eq.(4).

**Estimation of $u_0$ and $v_i$**

The ejection velocity is a critical parameter. In Eq.(5) the pull-down of gravity is divided by $u_0^2$. If $u_0$ is too small, the gravity will pull down the rocket. The parameter $u_0$ has to contain the information of $x_0$, to counter balance the constant $u_0$. I suggest a reasonable estimate of $u_0$ as:

$$
   P_f = P_0 \frac{L - x_0}{L};
$$
and estimate $u_0$ using this final pressure (when $x=0$) from Bernoulli Equation:

$$
  u_0 = \lambda \sqrt{2 P_0 \frac{L - x_0}{L-0.5 x_0}}
$$
Where $\lambda$ is an adjustable parameter to fit the real situation.

Also $v_i$ is final burst impulse, considering the work done as the pressure lower down to $1 atm$ under free expansion, I suggest:

$$
  v_i = \lambda' \sqrt{\left(P_f - P_{atm}\right) * A * L / m_0}
$$

Again, the parameter, $\lambda'$ is employed to fit the real situation.

An example of speed as function of time ($x_0 = 15 cm, L = 30 cm$):

[image]

And the height as function of $x_o$ using $\lambda = 0.5$ and setting $v_i = 0$:

[image]

Comment: Good answer! I made some minor (spelling) edits.

Comment: @Gert Thank. Air resistance is another important factor should be considered.

Comment: You mean drag? I mentioned that. Thanks.